# Bash array question: How to add files from a directory into an array in a shell script

Tags: arrays, bash

I’m having trouble getting a list of files into an array.  `arr=( * )` works when i’m in the directory in question, but `arr=( path-to-dir/* )` dosen’t seem to work.

`arr=( $(ls -1 path-to-dir)` works, but from my understanding, using ls -1 is not a good idea.

What’s the best way to capture the files in a directory into an array if it’s not in your $PWD?

Comment: `arr=( path-to-dir/* )` seems ok, what's wrong with it?

Comment: I just tried it again, but I think i see what’s going on. My filenames are all rc files so they begin with `.`

Comment: Looks like that method ignores files that begin with a `.` Do you know how to include them?

Comment: `arr=( path-to-dir/.* )`?? or `shopt -s dotglob` then `arr=( path-to-dir/* )`

Comment: I tried `arr=( path-to-dir/,* )` but it adds the `.` and `..` as the first two elements of the array. I can just skip these when I call the array, but I was hoping for a more elegant solution.

Comment: Also that solution skips all files without a `.`

Comment: ```declare -a rc_dir_output
 local rc_dir_output=( $rc_dir/.* )

declare -i rc_dir_output_length
local rc_dir_output_length=${#rc_dir_output[@]}

declare -a rc_files
local rc_files=( ${rc_dir_output[@]: 2: $rc_dir_output_length} )

for rc in ${rc_files[@]}
  do
    rc_basename=${rc##*/} #==> remove path```